# How can you pass in arguments to rake tasks called using Heroku Scheduler?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, rake-task

Rake tasks scheduled in Heroku found online are in the "rake `task-name`" format. Heroku passes in an :environment argument to the rake task, but there is no documentation about extra args being passed to a task listed in scheduler.rake

[Heroku Scheduler Doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
task :my_task, [:arg1, :arg2] => :environment do |t, args|
  puts "Args were: #{args}"
end
```

and then run manually to see the output:

```
heroku run rake my_task
```

UPDATE:

this answer can be an old one already

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but shouldn't that last line be `heroku run rake my_task arg1, arg2`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `rake task_name` input `rake task_name[arg1, arg2]` to the string input accepted by the Task column in the Heroku Scheduler main screen.

As mentioned by CodeGroover, your rake task defined in `lib/scheduler.rake` should define the parameters it is expecting.